# Incorrect number of rows per page in ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4oiGx5Au0YD4K4VKL0h0?p=preview) I have an ngTable generated with dynamic columns. The number of rows per page is 5, but as you can see the number of rows is 8 without pagination. Is this a defect or I'm doing something wrong?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl" ng-app="app">

  <table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td title="'Name'" ng-repeat="col in cols">{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {

      $scope.cols = [ {nm:'uid', title:'User ID'}, {nm:'ugr', title: 'Group ID'} ];


      $scope.data = [ 
        { uid: 'User 1',ugr: 'Group 1'},
        { uid: 'User 2', ugr: 'Group 2'},
        { uid: 'User 3', ugr: 'Group 3'},
        { uid: 'User 4', ugr: 'Group 4'},
        { uid: 'User 5', ugr: 'Group 5'},
        { uid: 'User 6', ugr: 'Group 6'},
        { uid: 'User 7', ugr: 'Group 7'},
        { uid: 'User 8', ugr: 'Group 8'}

      ];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count:5},{dataset: $scope.data});

});
```

Comment: A good example can be found here: https://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/jPxgzY?editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

`$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count:5},{dataset: $scope.data});`

should be 
`$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count:5},{data: $scope.data,counts: [5, 10]});`

Note how I used data instead of dataset (I think dataset is for tables without dynamic columns).

In your html, you should get the data from $data, and your columns from $columns. Those dollar sign variables refer to the variables provided to you by ng-table.

Your data was getting loaded directly from $scope.data, instead of using the data passed to NgTableParams.

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Also, you do not need to set td title, since you are already passing your cols to it.
http://plnkr.co/edit/U8eMbtzAlxIf6ftRtxZA?p=preview

Comment: I tried to replicate your answer with the only difference that the ngTable is in a directive instead of a controller. The table is displayed empty with no rows (only the titles are shown). Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: I've never used Ng Table inside a directive, but I guess the data is not being loaded properly. Try using dataset instead of data, or hardcoding the data array you are passing to the NgTableParams ( to make sure is not an issue with the scope).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your HTML code that does not make sense as the tr/td are not correctly created, I fix the issue in the following [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/07hdT8zSPY3DN89TSZ7j?p=preview)

Basically, I change the ng-repeat to generate the rows correctly

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
      {{user.uid}}</td>
    <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
      {{user.ugr}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your answer is incorrect as it removes the creation of the columns dynamically